# Getting User Current latitude longitude when App in InActive state and even App removes from background

Tags: ios, iphone, background

My app requires accessing the user's current latitude and longitude when the app is an active state. I can also get the user's location when the app is in the background.

But my question is, if the app is removed/killed in the background, can I still get the user's location?

Comment: Cleaning up grammar, spelling, formatting, etc. Made it a bit more coherent.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this section in the iOS Docs

Getting Location Events in the Background (iOS Only)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10

You can only receive location updates to an app that is not running by using Region Monitoring or the Significant Change Location Service.